# Application is extracting itself every time when runs

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, installshield

I have created an application with WPF and code is used C# but it gives a problem that whenever setup is silently installed with cmd command e.g.

```
setup.exe /s /v/qn
```

it works perfectly to extract all the items containing in it after above given lines. But once setup is completed we try to run this application, it executes but shows below given image
[image]

Setup is created in installshield and it has the option not extract msi cache in local computer. Please help me to find why this problem is occuring.

Comment: i got the same problem in my application........

Comment: Did you add manifest in your application ?  and try with /quite . either post your code. i already create control panel with silent installation.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx Go through dis

Comment: @ Dhru 'soni  I  tried your solution but the problem still remains, and it also increases the burden and every time gives the UAC popup when application runs.

Comment: In my case it installed correctly and the issue is when first time it runs, it shows the popup showing that configuring the system for the application i want to byPass that popup.

Comment: one more thing, in my setup there is an exe added in custom action which runs on the uninstallation.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to do with the auto-repair features of Windows Installer.

I guess you are using advertised shortcuts. Every time a user uses this special kind of shortcut to run a application, the Windows Installer performs an integrity check of it. If there are any detected problems, the installer performs an "Repair" before the launch of your application. This seems to be the case.

You can detect advertised shortcuts in the property-dialog of the start-menu. The target-field will be disabled and does not contain a path to a executable.

A possible workaround is to use regular shortcuts but this will not solve the real problem which causes the dialog to appear.

You could try to investigate further with ProcMon (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) and see if there are any problems during the startup. Another option you have is to force logging (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545723) and see if there are any information that will help you finding the cause of this error.

Another entry-point for the self-repair is the creation of COM-objects which come with your installer-package.